# Report error: ORA-0000: normal, successful completion In Oracle APEX Tabular Form

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, tabular-form

Im getting **Report error: ORA-0000: normal, successful completion Oracle Apex** in a Tabular Form Report.

I cant able to proceed with any operations in the Tabular Forms such as Add Rows and Delete Checked Operation.

Is this an error or some kind of notification exception?

Few columns in this tabular form is done through cascading from another column in the same tabular form using Application Process. Will this be a reason for this error?

I checked many forums, but I couldnt get a proper solution to solve this. Kindly help me out in this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When are you getting this message? On page submit? Can you reproduce this behaviour on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: Im getting this error on page load.

Comment: Okay, and what are you doing on page load? Are there dynamic actions which fire on page load? Is there plsql load being ran on page render? Have you tried to debug the page, looking at the debug log? What apex version are you on?

Comment: Im in APEX 4.1 and yaa I have a dynamic action in the page I disabled it and checked. Not working. 
Even before adding the first entry its showing this error.
You have any idea what this error is about?

Answer (score 0):

This actually means there is no error i.e An operation has completed normally, having met no exceptions.

Action: No action required.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem we faced, there is a firewall between db server and application server, but later we noticed that. When we listen to tcp network we notice FIN ACK flags. This flag closes the connection for a long time without request, I mean if it was idle for a long time. However, in the db server side, there was no check to see if there was a connection. The situation was corrected by restarting again. We continued by removing the firewall between db and application server.

Answer (score 0):

This error `Error (ORA-0000: normal, successful completion) Error while xyz prc`, In side the xyz.prc I am update date into a table. To that table data range partition is there for that data partition are not there.

Once created it got processed.